# Can i store paypal information like user id and password of paypal and credticard details for autorecharge functionalites.?

Tags: ios, ios7, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am developing an iphone app. which require autorecharge functionality in paypal with paypal account and also with paypal creditcard. How can i achieve this...i am using paypal sdk library for my app of ios

Comment: I need to do the same thing , do you know how now ?

Answer (score 3):

Well its not allowed as per guideline, But if it important feature of your application than you can straight forward ask user to allow + Show the warning about this Feature.

Also while uploading to itunes store mention this point - That your asking user permission to save for important functionality.

All the Best!!

Comment: ok...but do you have any idea how to achieve this functionality.

Comment: do you want to be auto recharge from any button action or in background ?

Comment: at the time of registration my app will ask user for his first payment and auto recharge amount and initial amount. And also ask for his permission to auto recharge if only user want to do so. so when user amount fall below predefine amount application will automatic recharge his application account from paypal account.

Comment: As per my understanding when user allow auto recharge than you want to activate auto renwable stuff using paypal, if so than,

1) When user check option Allow Auto Renew save value in BOOL as YES.
2) Create a NSTimer [as per your auto rechrge duration] of Method.
3) above method will excute when duration qualify and call paypal payment Method to excute it.

+1 to Jagdeep answer below.

Comment: ok...understood....and can you tell me more about thrid point....how to make call paypal payment method automatically with requried information and from where to get that information. for example at the time of payment user have to log in his paypal account and he have to enter his paypal id and password...or if he is paying by credit card then it require credit card number CVV and exp. date....so for autorecharge next time how to get all this parameter

Comment: Its up to how you can retrieve information but you can use NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval for calling Method on certain duration.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41612/discussion-between-vivek-and-user3016693)

Comment: yes but my app will not need NSTimer because it will recharge user account automatically when his credit goes below to predefine limit. So i have I have to call autopayment method at that time....but my main issue is that how to retrive that information

Answer (score 0):

**You can use two options**

1) Use `NSUserDefult` to save data, also create  method which call paypal payment proccssing menthod in some auto thread or TImer
as per your condtion.

2) You can save CC info in some text file and use below code for Process

[PayPalPaymentViewController setEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork];

```
NSString *aPayerId = @"someuser@somedomain.com";

  // Create a PayPalPaymentViewController with the credentials and payerId, the PayPalPayment
  // from the previous step, and a PayPalPaymentDelegate to handle the results.
  PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController;
  paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithClientId:@"YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
                                                                  receiverEmail:@"YOUR_PAYPAL_EMAIL_ADDRESS"
                                                                        payerId:aPayerId
                                                                        payment:payment
                                                                       delegate:self];

  // Present the PayPalPaymentViewController.
  [self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Keep tow thing in mind -**

1 - Keep CC info encripted

2 - Aware user about this.

Comment: here what is aPayerId? Id through which user will login to his paypal account?? and secong thing how to get CC information.? becuse user has enter their CC info in paypal pages..Can i get that info???

Comment: Provide a payerId that uniquely identifies a user within the scope of your system, such as an email address or user ID. To get CC info you need to crate your own View.

Comment: so that means if i am using username as primary key to user then i can put username as aPayerId. and it is not related to paypal account id..right??? and you mean to say By Own view.... view which is created by me from which user can enter his credit card details????